# $\frac{1-a^3}{a}=\frac{1-b^3}{b}=\frac{1-c^3}{c}, a \neq b \neq c$; What is $a^3+b^3+c^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

> $\frac{1-a^3}{a}=\frac{1-b^3}{b}=\frac{1-c^3}{c}\\a \neq b \neq c\\a^3+b^3+c^3=$

Since $\frac{1-a^3}{a}=\frac{1-b^3}{b}$, $a^3=b^2a-\frac{a}{b}-1$.

$\therefore a^3+b^3+c^3=ab^2+bc^2+ca^2-\frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}-1$

Since $a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)+3abc$,

$ab^2+bc^2+ca^2-\frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}-1=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)+3abc$

(stuck here)

Comment: Trying to follow the reduction step in the first "since... Then $a^3+b^3+c^3=...$" won't there be a $-3$ at the end? And shouldn't the one term be $\frac{a^2c+b^2a+c^2a}{abc}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$a, b, c$ are roots of $$\frac{1-x^3}{x}=m$$

$$x^3+mx-1=0$$

Hence, we know that $a+b+c=0$ and $abc=1$ from Vieta's formula. Now you can use the identity that you stated to solve for $a^3+b^3+c^3$.

Comment: As a side note, you will never get the answer by just manipulating $a,b,c$'s, because these are equalities, and you never use the inequality $a\ne b \ne c$. By using Vieta's formula, you can utilize the inequality and solve the problem.

Comment: Nice +1. After the cubic is set, we can just sum it, like so:  $\sum a^3=3-m\sum a =3$.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't need to do any calculations.

---

We can construct a new cubic equation with roots $a^3,b^3,c^3.$

$$a^3=x_1,~ b^3=x_2,~ c^3=x_3$$

$$\begin{align}r=\frac{1-a^3}{a}=\frac{1-b^3}{
b}=\frac{1-c^3}{c}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}&\implies1-a^3=ar \\
&\implies(1-a^3)^3=a^3r^3 \\
&\implies(1-x)^3=xr^3 \\
&\implies1-3x+3x^2-x^3-xr^3=0 \\
&\implies x^3-3x^2+x(r^3+3)-1=0 \\
&\implies x_1+x_2+x_3=3 \\
&\implies a^3+b^3+c^3=3.\end{align}$$